# C Program: Create Linked List Using argv, argc, Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, command-line, linked-list, argv, argc

I have a program that takes in strings using the command line prompts argv and argc. I keep getting a segmentation fault when I go to run the code and after much researching, I cannot determine what might be causing this. Maybe how I execute the code is the issue? I am using gcc -o code code.c then ./code one two three with one two three being the strings added to the linked list. Any assistance in determining where my error might be would be great.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list_node_s{
    char the_char;
    struct list_node_s *next_node;
}list_node;

void insert_node(list_node *the_head, char the_char);
void print_list(list_node *the_head);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char next_char;
    list_node *the_head = NULL;
    insert_node(the_head, next_char);
    the_head->next_node = malloc(sizeof(list_node));
    if(the_head == NULL){
            return 1;
    }

    the_head->the_char = 1;
    the_head->next_node == NULL;
    int the_count, the_count2;
    for(the_count = 0; the_count < sizeof(argv); the_count++){
            for(the_count2 = 0; argv[the_count][the_count2] != '\0'; the_count2++){
                    next_char = argv[the_count][the_count2];
                    insert_node(the_head, next_char);
            }
    }

    print_list(the_head);
    return (0);
}

void insert_node(list_node *the_head, char the_char){
    list_node * current_node = the_head;
    while (current_node->next_node != NULL) {
        current_node = current_node->next_node;
    }

    current_node->next_node = malloc(sizeof(list_node));
    current_node->next_node->the_char = the_char;
    current_node->next_node->next_node = NULL;
}

void print_list(list_node *the_head){
    if(the_head == NULL){
            printf("\n");
    }else{
            printf("%c", the_head->the_char);
            print_list(the_head->next_node);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your cut and paste? what is `the_co$`?

Comment: `sizeof(argv)` is almost certainly not what you want to use as a `for` limit. `argv` is a pointer, its size has nothing to do with the number of arguments. That's what `argc` is for.

Comment: the line the_head->next_node == NULL is almost certainly wrong. You probably wanted to say = (line 27)

Comment: next_char is uninitialized before it's being used (line 20). Try to remove the compiler warnings. Both comments from my side are compiler warnings (VS2013)

Comment: When you call `insert_node(the_head, next_char)` at the beginning of `main()`, `the_head` is NULL, so you get an fault when `insert_node` tries to dereference it. And `next_char` is uninitialized.

Comment: @Barmer: correct, that's also where I'm getting the segfault. Additional advice: the compiler gives hints where the segfault is. Try to use that information or present it here if you want help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
list_node *the_head = NULL;
insert_node(the_head, next_char);
the_head->next_node = malloc(sizeof(list_node));
```

to:

```
list_node the_head = { '\0', NULL };
```

to initialize `the_head` to an empty node.

Comment: This is what I was talking about @Ichristina26

Answer (score 1):

One problem is in this function:

```
void insert_node(list_node *the_head, char the_char){
    list_node * current_node = the_head;
    while (current_node->next_node != NULL) {
        current_node = current_node->next_node;
    }

    current_node->next_node = malloc(sizeof(list_node));
    current_node->next_node->the_char = the_char;
    current_node->next_node->next_node = NULL;
}
```

When you call it in `main` you're basically passing in `NULL` because you're setting `the_head` to `NULL`. You're trying to access `current_node->next_node` in the while loop conditions, but because of what you're passing in, you're basically doing `NULL->next_node`.

You need to initialize your head to an empty `list_node`. Basically since you're using a `char` as your node element you could set the value of the char to `0x00`, which would make it a zero byte. Then that way you know that when you're at that value, you're at the head.

I don't mean to self-promote, but if you want to look at some code for this have a look at this github repo for the [Barry_CS-331 Data Structures class](https://github.com/HugoSTorres/Barry_CS-331). There's C and C++ in there for the Data Structures. I think it might have a list but if not you can use the stack and the queue as an overall example.

Comment: So am I initializing the head to 0x00 in the main method or in the insert method? Or am I initializing one of my chars? I tried a few things off of what you said and nothing seemed to work so I'm assuming I'm doing it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list_node_s{
    char the_char;
    struct list_node_s *next_node;
}list_node;

void insert_node(list_node *the_head, char the_char);
void print_list(list_node *the_head);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    list_node *the_head = NULL;
    int the_count, the_count2;

    for(the_count = 0; the_count < argc; the_count++)
        {
        for(the_count2 = 0; the_count2 < strlen(argv[the_count]); the_count2++)
            insert_node(&the_head, argv[the_count][the_count2]);
        }

    print_list(the_head);
    return (0);
    }

void insert_node(list_node **the_head, char the_char){
    list_node *new_node;
    list_node *tail_node;

    /* Allocate and populate a new node. */
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(list_node));
    new_node->the_char = the_char;
    new_node->next_node = NULL;

   /* Is the_head already initialized? */ 
   if(*the_head)
       {
       /* Yes... find the tail_node. */
       tail_node = *the_head;
       while(tail_node->next)
           tail_node = tail_node->next;

       /* Append the new_node to the end of the list. */
       tail_node->next = new_node;
       return;
       }

    /* the_head was not initialized.  The new_node will be the head node. */
    *the_head = new_node;

    return;
    }

void print_list(list_node *the_head){
    if(the_head == NULL){
        printf("\n");
    }else{
        printf("%c", the_head->the_char);
        print_list(the_head->next_node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified you code, there has some bugs:

1)、the key bug is in this code.

```
 for(the_count = 0; the_count < sizeof(argv); the_count++)
 {
      for(the_count2 = 0; argv[the_count][the_count2] != '\0'; the_count2++)
      {
          next_char = argv[the_count][the_count2];
          insert_node(the_head, next_char);
      }
 }
```

there some bugs:
you cann't use `the_count < sizeof(argv)`, because of the type of `argv` is `char* []`; so `sizeof(argv)` maybe `4` or `8`, based on your os.

the right is:

```
 for(the_count = 1; the_count < argc; the_count++){
    for(the_count2 = 0; argv[the_count][the_count2] != '\0'; the_count2++){
      next_char = argv[the_count][the_count2];
      insert_node(the_head, next_char);
    }   
  }
```

2、this code aose has some bugs:

```
list_node *the_head = NULL;
insert_node(the_head, next_char);
the_head->next_node = malloc(sizeof(list_node));
if(the_head == NULL){
        return 1;
}

the_head->the_char = 1;
the_head->next_node == NULL;
```

`insert_node(the_head, next_char);` is no need, you'd better do `the_head->the_char = '\0'`, because of char `1` is no printable character.